# Strange desktop wallpaper at Xubuntu 14.04 startup:

Tags: xubuntu, startup, desktop-background

When i start my computer i have this:
[image: strange desktop wallpaper]
After 2-3 seconds the menu loads, my normal wallpaper and all other, but why is this showing is it something to worry about and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a wallpaper, but the result of a minor graphics driver bug/incompatibility. You could try another driver if it is available for your graphics card and if you find it annoying (check software center > Edit > Software Sources, choose the *Additional Drivers* tab to see if there are other drivers available).